# gstreamer 1.16 to 1.18 update queue is dropping buffers with "queue is full, leaking item"

Tags: c++, gstreamer, glib, gstreamer-1.0, gobject

I have a pipeline streaming from webrtc and sent to other webrtc peers with
an input-selector and tee

I am using **queue** in between **tee** and **rtpvp8pay/rtpopuspay**

With *GStreamer 1.16.2* the queue logs few messages as below, but forwards
buffers to rtp*pay,

/

```
0:00:42.691994561 [334m  117[00m 0x7f4f00024540 [37mDEBUG  [00m [00m    
queue_dataflow gstqueue.c:1242:gst_queue_chain_buffer_or_list:<queue4>[00m
queue is full, waiting for free space
0:00:42.703688771 [334m  117[00m 0x7f4f00024540 [37mDEBUG  [00m [00m    
queue_dataflow gstqueue.c:1242:gst_queue_chain_buffer_or_list:<queue4>[00m
queue is full, waiting for free space
0:00:42.708788498 [334m  117[00m 0x7f4f00024540 [37mDEBUG  [00m [00m    
queue_dataflow gstqueue.c:1242:gst_queue_chain_buffer_or_list:<queue4>[00m
queue is full, waiting for free space
0:00:43.465747577 [334m  117[00m 0x7f4f00024540 [37mDEBUG  [00m [00m    
queue_dataflow gstqueue.c:1242:gst_queue_chain_buffer_or_list:<queue4>[00m
queue is full, waiting for free space
0:00:44.524233433 [334m  117[00m 0x7f4f00024540 [37mDEBUG  [00m [00m    
queue_dataflow gstqueue.c:1242:gst_queue_chain_buffer_or_list:<queue4>[00m
queue is full, waiting for free space
0:00:46.610925338 [334m  117[00m 0x7f4f00024540 [37mDEBUG  [00m [00m    
queue_dataflow gstqueue.c:1242:gst_queue_chain_buffer_or_list:<queue4>[00m
queue is full, waiting for free space
0:00:49.789920943 [334m  117[00m 0x7f4f00024540 [37mDEBUG  [00m [00m    
queue_dataflow gstqueue.c:1242:gst_queue_chain_buffer_or_list:<queue4>[00m
queue is full, waiting for free space
0:00:50.853170574 [334m  117[00m 0x7f4f00024230 [37mDEBUG  [00m [00m    
queue_dataflow gstqueue.c:1242:gst_queue_chain_buffer_or_list:<queue4>[00m
queue is full, waiting for free space
0:00:52.944611891 [334m  117[00m 0x7f4f00024540 [37mDEBUG  [00m [00m    
queue_dataflow gstqueue.c:1242:gst_queue_chain_buffer_or_list:<queue4>[00m
queue is full, waiting for free space
0:00:55.448559169 [334m  117[00m 0x7f4f00024540 [37mDEBUG  [00m [00m    
queue_dataflow gstqueue.c:1242:gst_queue_chain_buffer_or_list:<queue4>[00m
queue is full, waiting for free space
```

/

But when running the same pipeline on **GStreamer 1.18** queue just drops all
buffers with message as below,

/

```
0:00:21.236543341 [333m 1994[00m 0x7fc4b4049050 [37mDEBUG  [00m [00m    
queue_dataflow
gstqueue.c:1148:gst_queue_leak_downstream:<queue_audio-ue_1351510000>[00m
queue is full, leaking item 0x7fc46000ea20 on downstream end
0:00:21.247554410 [333m 1994[00m 0x7fc4b40490f0 [37mDEBUG  [00m [00m    
queue_dataflow
gstqueue.c:1148:gst_queue_leak_downstream:<queue_video-ue_1351510000>[00m
queue is full, leaking item 0x563030fe3ea0 on downstream end
0:00:21.254694194 [333m 1994[00m 0x7fc4b4049050 [37mDEBUG  [00m [00m    
queue_dataflow
gstqueue.c:1148:gst_queue_leak_downstream:<queue_audio-ue_1351510000>[00m
queue is full, leaking item 0x7fc4700e56c0 on downstream end
0:00:21.276942385 [333m 1994[00m 0x7fc4b4049050 [37mDEBUG  [00m [00m    
queue_dataflow
gstqueue.c:1148:gst_queue_leak_downstream:<queue_audio-ue_1351510000>[00m
queue is full, leaking item 0x7fc46000eea0 on downstream end
0:00:21.282223742 [333m 1994[00m 0x7fc4b40490f0 [37mDEBUG  [00m [00m    
queue_dataflow
gstqueue.c:1148:gst_queue_leak_downstream:<queue_video-ue_1351510000>[00m
queue is full, leaking item 0x7fc4ac019000 on downstream end
0:00:21.295608065 [333m 1994[00m 0x7fc4b4049050 [37mDEBUG  [00m [00m    
queue_dataflow
gstqueue.c:1148:gst_queue_leak_downstream:<queue_audio-ue_1351510000>[00m
queue is full, leaking item 0x7fc46000eb40 on downstream end
0:00:21.313417281 [333m 1994[00m 0x7fc4b4049050 [37mDEBUG  [00m [00m    
queue_dataflow
gstqueue.c:1148:gst_queue_leak_downstream:<queue_audio-ue_1351510000>[00m
queue is full, leaking item 0x563030fe3480 on downstream end
0:00:21.314284947 [333m 1994[00m 0x7fc4b40490f0 [37mDEBUG  [00m [00m    
queue_dataflow
gstqueue.c:1148:gst_queue_leak_downstream:<queue_video-ue_1351510000>[00m
**queue is full, leaking item 0x563030fe3240 on downstream end**
0:00:21.336302609 [333m 1994[00m 0x7fc4b4049050 [37mDEBUG  [00m [00m    
queue_dataflow
gstqueue.c:1148:gst_queue_leak_downstream:<queue_audio-ue_1351510000>[00m
queue is full, leaking item 0x563030fe3360 on downstream end
0:00:21.347706535 [333m 1994[00m 0x7fc4b40490f0 [37mDEBUG  [00m [00m    
queue_dataflow
gstqueue.c:1148:gst_queue_leak_downstream:<queue_video-ue_1351510000>[00m
queue is full, leaking item 0x7fc4700e57e0 on downstream end
0:00:21.354814503 [333m 1994[00m 0x7fc4b4049050 [37mDEBUG  [00m [00m    
queue_dataflow
gstqueue.c:1148:gst_queue_leak_downstream:<queue_audio-ue_1351510000>[00m
queue is full, leaking item 0x563030fe37e0 on downstream end
0:00:21.377144606 [333m 1994[00m 0x7fc4b4049050 [37mDEBUG  [00m [00m    
queue_dataflow
gstqueue.c:1148:gst_queue_leak_downstream:<queue_audio-ue_1351510000>[00m
queue is full, leaking item 0x7fc4a000dd80 on downstream end
```

/

I have verified by applying PAD_PROBE's on srcPad and sinkPad of queues and
it was clear that queue receives buffers on sinkPad but not sent out from
srcPad

I have applied leaky on queue as below which was as working from GStreamer
1.16 setup, I tried to flip it on and off but no luck,

/g_object_set(audioqueue, "leaky", 2, NULL);/

Attached detail log file  gst_debug.txt
http://gstreamer-devel.966125.n4.nabble.com/file/t378374/gst_debug.txt

I do observe one commit coming on 1.18 release with regard to 'leaky queue'
https://github.com/GStreamer/gstreamer/commit/3260b2f630d4cc06b9a86bddd11d569ad030f360#diff-4920d773f9dad342122e70ef31a76728

Do I need to set any additional configs to manage this

Any suggestions/directions please...

Thanks

Comment: Try setting the `leaky` property on the [queue](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/coreelements/queue.html?gi-language=c#queue:leaky) element.

Comment: @theUser I tried leaky:2 as it was same with ver 1.16 (https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/coreelements/queue.html?gi-language=c#GstQueueLeaky) i,e downstream but it didn't help